# "Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference" with "grouping set"

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, grouping-sets

I have the following SQL query, my goal was to make a subtotal and a general tota, grouping the subtotals by products, but my problem would be that if I use only the "group by" he would have to add all the fields of the "select", and the result would not be the desired one. So I tried to use the "grouping set", but it gives the following error

> **"Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference"**

Would anyone have a solution either for the above problem or to be able to group only by product?

```
SELECT 
    p.id_product,
    p.name,
    dd.name ,
    isnull(p.internal code, '------'),
    {fn CONCAT(CAST(d.id_division AS varchar), {fn CONCAT(' - ', d.name)}) },
    sum(vs.value1),
    sum(p.value2),
    sum(p.value2 * vs.value1)
FROM product p
    LEFT JOIN division d on d.id_division  = p.id_division
    LEFT JOIN division2 dd on dd.id_product = p.id_product
    LEFT JOIN value_stockroom vs on vs.id_product = p.id_product and vs.id_division2 = dd.id_division2
GROUP BY
    GROUPING SETS((p.id_product, p.name), (dd.name), (p.internal_code), (d.id_division, d.name), NULL)
ORDER BY 
    p.name, p.id_product, d.name
```

I'm new using the `Grouping set` clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NULL` is not allowed in `GROUP BY` because it is a constant.  You want empty parentheses:

```
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS( (p.id_product, p.name), 
                        (dd.name),
                        (p.internal_code),
                        (d.id_division, d.name),
                        ()
                      )
```

Comment: is it possible to group only by product or something?